# TSQL Transpose a column of a table into a row

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have a temporary table with one column containing 3 pieces of data: `Code`, `Date`, and `Quantity`.

Example:

```
-------
FR123456
24/02/1988
500
```

I need to extract the data in this column into separate columns.

Example:

```
Code     | Date       | Quantity
---------  -----------  ---- 
FR123456 | 24/02/1988 | 500
```

I used this code:

```sql
SELECT [1], [2], [3]
FROM  
(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY splitdata DESC) AS Id, splitdata  
    FROM splitdata 
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
    MIN (splitdata)
    FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

The problem with it is that once the content of data changes, I may get the quantity content into the date column due to the aggregate function (MIN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is SQL-Server related...

Your problem is: A SQL-Server table does not have any kind of implicit sort order. A simple `SELECT * FROM SomeWhere` can return in the sort order you've inserted your data, but can return completely different as well. The only chance to ensure a sort order is an `ORDER BY` at the outer-most query against a (set of) unique column(s).

You can create a sort order by kind of analysing your data:

This is a *mockup-table* with your test data:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(YourColumn VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
  ('FR123456')
 ,('24/02/1988')
 ,('500');
```

--The query will check the values if they can be casted to a number, to a date or not.
--This will be used to place a sort order to the values.
--I use `105` in `CONVERT` to enforce the dateformat *dd-MM-yyyy*

```sql
 SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE,YourColumn,105) IS NOT NULL THEN 2
             ELSE CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(YourColumn AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN 3 ELSE 1 
                  END 
        END AS SortOrder
        ,YourColumn
 FROM @mockup
 ORDER BY SortOrder;
```

But if there are several triplets in your table, not just one as in your sample, I'm afraid you're lost...

Btw: Your own approach tries to do exactly the same:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (order by splitdata desc)as Id
```

This will create kind of a *sort order number*, but it will be random (a quantity will appeare before or after the date depending on alphanumerical rules).

### Hint

Add an `IDENTITY` column to your table. This will use an increasing number for any row the moment it is created. These values can be used to enforce the order *as inserted* (by using `ORDER BY` with this column).

### UPDATE: Your query

```
 SELECT [1], [2] , [3]
    FROM  
    (SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE,splitdata,105) IS NOT NULL THEN 2
             ELSE CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(splitdata AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN 3 ELSE 1 
                  END 
        END AS Id , splitdata  
    from @mockup ) AS SourceTable  
    PIVOT  
    (  
    MIN (splitdata)
    FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3])  
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Shnugo. This helps a lot